# Hiding part of a layer in timeline animation

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I wanted to create a snow animation inside a round shape using the Photoshop CC timeline. To do that, I created a bigger layer of snow moving downwards through the smaller sphere. 
I don't want to display the snow outside the sphere but I can't erase any part of it because I need every bit of the snow layer to create the animation.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you would just have to place any/all layers that are to be contained in the small sphere in a folder/group.  Then just apply a mask to that layer group. Let me know if that works?

Comment: It works perfectly!!!
I'm sorry for the silly question but I'm a total beginner with masks! Thank you so much!

Comment: @ErickP could you leave that as an answer so Titania can accept it instead of leaving this as unanswered. Helps us keep the site organized and you'll both earn some rep too.

Comment: @Ryan:  Done. Thx.  I forget and just add comment by habit.

Answer (score 1):

You would just have to place any/all layers that are to be contained in the small sphere in a folder/group. Then just apply a mask to that layer group.